# What is the difference between a kite and a glider?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, drag, aerodynamics, aircraft

A kite and a glider, both fly without an engine. If both are unpowered, then what is the difference between a kite and a glider? Are all gliders kites? Or are all kites gliders? How do they differ? What comes under what?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the word "stall" in relation to airfoils? An airfoil is stalled when the air can no longer follow the top surface. So no, gliders are not kites. Kites are stalled airfoils. Gliders are not stalled (unless the pilot purposely stalls the wings by pulling back hard on the stick, which they generally do not want to do).

Answer (score 0):

A [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite) is tethered whereas a [glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(aircraft)) is free flying. Most gliders are designed to carry a pilot and so have some sort of rigid airframe - but a [paraglider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragliding) is basically a big free flying kite with a seat attached.

Comment: No. A kite flies stalled.